# Second testMethod failing Selenium C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, selenium, visual-studio-2012

Here's my code :

```
[TestInitialize]
    public void init()
    {
        _browser = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, @"*iehta", "http://localhost:4444");
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public  void TestLogin()
    {
        bool hasText;


        _browser.Start();

        _browser.Open("http://localhost/testSite.asp");
        _browser.Type("id=NomUtilisateur", "admin");
        _browser.Type("id=UserPassword", "password");
        _browser.Click("name=Submit");
        _browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        hasText = _browser.IsTextPresent("test");

        Assert.IsTrue(hasText, @"The search result does not contain text ""test"".");




    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRequisitionPhotocopie()
    {

        _browser.Start();
        _browser.Open("http://localhost/testSite.asp");
        _browser.Type("id=NomUtilisateur", "admin");
        _browser.Type("id=UserPassword", "password");
        _browser.Click("name=Submit");
        _browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        _browser.Click("link=lnkTest");
        _browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");


    }
    [TestCleanup]
    public void clean()
    {
        _browser.Stop();
        //_browser.Close();
    }
```

If I run the two test method, the secon test always fail with an error message like this : 
Remote server don't exist or is unavaible

If I comment one of the test method, it's working, my two test method are working

Where's my mistake.

Thanks

EDIT : 
The error is not happening everytime, but the error is in Selenium Remote Control If i debug the error is in selenium-browserbot.js at line 724 :  windowToModify.seleniumAlert = windowToModify.alert;

Selenium log console have nothing in it

Comment: You should check any available log files you have - looks like either starting Selenium Server fails for test 2, or you don't cleanly shut it down after test 1. It's hard to tell without any log output though.

Comment: Where are the log ? But it'S IE that's giving me an error ...

Comment: I don't know where your setup might store logfiles about the test runs ;) So you're getting an error in IE that the remote server doesn't respond, it's not an error from Selenium?

Comment: Is it ok to call browser.Start twice without stoping it between? init happens only once for both of your test methods and their share the same browser instance

Comment: @Nikolay I've tried puting the stop in my testMethod  and it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: How about to not just stop browser but recreate it in each Test method?

Comment: @Nikolay i've tried it too, and nothing change :(

Comment: Phew, looks like one of those beloved intermittent ghost failures around Selenium and IE, which is why we decided to test in Firefox only and do IE manually. I'll revisit the question later, maybe someone else has experience with that problem.

Comment: To rule out whether its IE & Selenium combination did you try using FF browser instead of IE?

Comment: It's working in FF but i really need my test to be done in IE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this? I always start selenium in the setup of the test. (i'm  also using Nunit

```
[SetUp]
public void init()
{
    _browser = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, @"*iehta",   "http://localhost:4444");
    _browser.Start();
    _browser.Open("http://localhost/testSite.asp");
}


[TestMethod]
public  void TestLogin()
{
    bool hasText;



    _browser.Type("id=NomUtilisateur", "admin");
    _browser.Type("id=UserPassword", "password");
    _browser.Click("name=Submit");
    _browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    hasText = _browser.IsTextPresent("test");

    Assert.IsTrue(hasText, @"The search result does not contain text ""test"".");




}
[TestMethod]
public void TestRequisitionPhotocopie()
{
    _browser.Type("id=NomUtilisateur", "admin");
    _browser.Type("id=UserPassword", "password");
    _browser.Click("name=Submit");
    _browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
    _browser.Click("link=lnkTest");
    _browser.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");


}
[TearDown]
public void clean()
{
    _browser.Stop();
    //_browser.Close();
}
```